# How do I add animation / styling to a button? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:onClick="loginIsClicked"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/Auth"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:enabled="false" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

How can I add animation to the button used in the default buttons?

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i6Fm.gif)

Comment: In your gif there is no button. I think it's a `CardView` with `focusable="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you are looking for is a **ripple**. Wrap your shape in a ripple as follows and provide your ripple color:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/rippleColor">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `MaterialButton`.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Also do not forget to change theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` in `styles.xml` file.